# Smoke + fire simulation disappears after baking noise

Tags: smoke-simulation

After I bake my noise there is nothing to see anymore.
I can only see it with color mapping on under viewport display. But that doesn't help me with the render.

In viewport with color mapping on:
[image: With color mapping on]

In material preview:
[image: Viewport shading]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check "Is Resumable" in the Cache section of the smoke domain physics properties.

For some background, I was having a similar issue. After doing some digging, I found this answer here: https://developer.blender.org/T80372

"This was a usability issue: Baking noise in the modular cache mode is only possible when also enabling the resumable option."

I wanted to make sure I knew what I was turning on by checking that option, so I will share this from the Blender manual as well: "Use Resumable Cache: Extra data will be saved so that you can resumed baking after pausing. Since more data will be written to drive it is recommended to avoid enabling this option when baking at high resolutions."